# Upload image to Firebase using Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I have a Django rest API, in which there is an API to get an image from formdata.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser 
from rest_framework import status


from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.conf import settings
import os
import io

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view



import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, storage

cred = credentials.Certificate("JSON FILE PATH")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'storageBucket': 'BUCKET URL'})



@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        if(type(data)!=dict):
            data=data.dict()
        file_obj=data['image']
        fileName=file_obj.name
        blob=bucket.blob(fileName)
        blob.upload_from_file(file_obj.file)
        blob.make_public()

        print("File url", blob.public_url)

        return JsonResponse({'username':'Testing post response'})
    
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return JsonResponse({'username':'Testing get response'})
```

Now, when I send an image in formdata, it is uploading in firebase but not in image format, instead, it is uploading as application/octet-stream type and image is not being displayed. can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
blob.upload_from_file(file_obj.file)

**to**

blob.upload_from_file(file_obj, content_type = file_obj.content_type)
```